# What does this Regex mean in Java? "(\\d+(\\.\\d+)?)"

Tags: java, regex

The code is:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+(\\.\\d+)?)");
```

Comment: just replace \\ with \ (because java needs escaping in Strings) and you have a regex, then you can check yourself what that means

Comment: float point like like 123.342

Comment: Visit this page : https://regex101.com, and check your Regex

Comment: It will match a whole number, optionally followed by a decimal point and decimal component.

Comment: See the API documentation of class [`java.util.regex.Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Answer (score 2):

```
a. \d implies digit.
b. + sign implies one or more occurance of previous character.
c. \. -> since . is a special character in regex, we have to escape it with \.
d. Also, \ is a special escape character in java , hence from java perspective we need to add an additional \ to escape the backslash (\).
```

Thus, the pattern will reprent any number like:
0.01, 0.001, 1.0001, 100.00001 and so on.
Basically any decimal number with a digit before and after the decimal point.

Answer (score 0):

The regex is a simplified version to recognize floating-point numbers: At least one digit optionally followed by a dot and at least a digit.

It's simplified because it only covers only number without a sign (i.e. only positive numbers, because you can't provide a `-` minus sign), it allows number presentations that are considered invalid, e.g. `000123.123` and lacks the support of numbers written in scientific syntax (e.g. `1.234e56`).